# Не работает git push

Tags: linux, git, git-push

Git push выводит:

> fatal: Текущая ветка master не имеет вышестоящей ветки.
> Чтобы отправить текущую ветку и установить внешнюю ветку как вышестоящую для этой ветки, используйте
>
> git push --set-upstream origin master

git push --set-upstream origin master выводит

> error: src refspec master does not match any.
> error: не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в «https://github.com/RrIiDdIiKk/asds.git»

Как это исправить?

Comment: Тысячный дубликат...

Comment: @Oandriy, даже если и дубликат и что? Я искал вопросы по этой теме, и ничего конкретного не нашёл, и после возражений аля "значит плохо искал" и т.д. отвечу даже вопрос приведенный KoVadim  был написан аж 7 (почти 8) лет назад